# Is there nice tutorial of -how to create iphone 4.0 that support multitasking?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there nice tutorial of -how to create iphone 4.0  that support multitasking ?

meaning, create simple app in iphone 4.0 o.s that will continue working while in background and when return to forground i will see the right progress status.

hope im clear.

thanking in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Since version 4 of iPhone OS is still under NDA, you are going to be limited to what is available at http://developer.apple.com. They have some documents describing what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how iPhone 4.0 SDK works, you cannot make your App run in the background, you have access to 7 different services, which are internal services, that you have to pass information to.

Like Background Music works when you supply internal service with URI as to where to pick up the information for the next music stream.

Or background task completion isn't really running your task, what it's doing is downloading or uploading using internal built in services that keep doing its work even after the app is closed, but when app is re started it could request the status.