# Move iphone application in background on cALL

Tags: iphone

I want to move application on background won call or when user press home button.
Please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there nice tutorial of -how to create iphone 4.0  that support multitasking ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830168/is-there-nice-tutorial-of-how-to-create-iphone-4-0-that-support-multitasking)

Answer (score 0):

A great place to start learning about iOS multitasking is the [iOS Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1). Specifically, the sections on the [application life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW17), [multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1), and [executing code in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW4).